# What is the purpose of failover group for Azure SQL if it already is highly available?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

According to documentation below, Azure SQL databases are already a high-availability service.  If that's the case, then what is the purpose of configuring failover groups?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-high-availability

Are failover groups more for when you have a hybrid architecture with a SQL server on-premise and would like to leverage the cloud for disaster recovery?

Comment: You cannot configure AGs with Azure SQL Database.

Comment: I've added a couple snapshots.  I mixed up terminology.  It's failover groups that I'm referring to.  Sorry.

Comment: That's Active Geo Replication which is a Disaster Recovery and Read Scale feature.   See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview

Comment: That's what I thought, but doesn't high availability cover disaster recovery in Azure?  I guess that's where I'm confused.  Or is highly available implemented within the same region.  If the regional data center goes down, then the failover group would fire off in a different region?

Comment: Yes Azure SQL Database always includes DR, but Active Geo Replication gives you faster failover, possibly less data loss and more control.  Basically if you need to minimize application downtime in a DR scenario, then use Active Geo Replication.  Otherwise just use the Geo Restore. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups

Comment: Thanks.  Does the new Zone redundant configuration feature apply here?  Seems that it addresses the regional data center issue.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview

Comment: All the Availability Zones are in the same Region, so it wouldn't protect against a regional issue like a natural disaster.

Comment: Thank you for all the info...super helpful.  Do you want to provide an answer so I can accept : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [Active Geo Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview) which is a Disaster Recovery and Read Scale feature.

Azure SQL Database always includes DR, but Active Geo Replication gives you faster failover, possibly less data loss and more control. Basically if you need to minimize application downtime in a DR scenario, then use Active Geo Replication. Otherwise just use the [Geo Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups).